# Multiple GET arguments

Tags: php, arguments

I've been working with PHP lately, and I came across something I couldn't solve.

So basically, I have a form:

```
<form method="get">
    <fieldset class="display-options" style="float: left">
    Search by name or ip:
        <input type="text" name="key" value="" />&nbsp;
        <input type="submit" class="button2" value="Search" />
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

The problem is, I currently already have a argument:

```
http://example.com/logs.php?type=admin&page=1
```

How would i pass the given form argument with the already existing arguments? Like so:

```
http://example.com/logs.php?type=admin&page=1&key=name
```

Thanks in advance, AJ.

Comment: Doesn't it already do that when you submit the form?  I'm pretty sure get requests just tack the input parameters onto the URL.

Comment: @R0MANARMY, It doesn't do this for me. It either doesn't work for me, or doesn't exist at all.

Comment: No, it'll throw away any existing arguments and start afresh. At least, all sane browsers will.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<snip />

**EDIT**: hidden fields is your best and most reliable option.

```
<input type="hidden" name="var1" value="<?php echo $_GET['var1']; ?>" />
```

Place a couple of those in your `<form>` element and they'll get passed along with the other data.

You shouldn't need an `isset()` but it might be a good idea.

Comment: Better you edit your answer to leave only one working solution with hidden fields :)

Comment: your <snip> tag isn't properly formed.. should be `<snip />`  8p

Comment: I suppose if I use XHTML in my snippet, I should use it in my documentation as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (isset($_GET['key'])) {
    $_print_r($_GET);
}
```

This should have the query string and the fields.